# SFML dlls not found

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

When I tried to run this using CodeBlocks. I got this error:

> The procedure entry point `_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringlcSt11char_traitslcESalcEE7reserveEj` could not be located in the dynamic link library `xxxxx\bin\Debug\sfml-system-2.dll`

What does this mean?

Comment: I'm sorry. I had to use screenshot because the error itself can't be copied. It was a popped up window, and I don't know why it can't be highlighted, and the error is too long too type. :(

I will be less lazy next time, and type the errors if it can't be copied. 
Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

You should copy *sfml-system-2.dll etc.* dll files from `*\SFML-2.3.2\bin\` folder to your project `xxxxx\bin\Debug\`

// SFML-2.3.2 - is a library which you downloaded, u can have other version

I think your compiler works fine, but system can't run builded program, because system can't find necessary dll files. That's why you must copy dll's from sfml library to folder where you have builded .exe